# не сохраняется boot priority

Tags: bios, uefi

asrock steel legend b550
Есть 3 диска: 1 ssd на котором винда и 2 hdd, загружается hdd, ставлю в boot priority нужный диск - загружается винда, перезагружаю - снова загружается hdd, если этот hdd вынуть то загружается винда
Другие настройки в биосе сохраняются, проверял на подсветке материнки

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/472279